# How to replace DevExpress ASP.NET calendar with my own?

Tags: calendar, replace, devexpress

We're using DevExpress control toolkit for our ASP.NET application. I would like to replace the DevExpress default dropdown calendar with my own because of the following reasons:

- DevExpress dropdown calendar gets positioned absolutely next to the textbox it is assigned to. This is bad, because on IE it gets obscured by other relatively-positioned elements that are siblings to the calendars parents. It can be worked around by setting a lot of z-indexes on these parent elements, but that's annoying. It would be way better if the calendars elements would be at the very end of the DOM with a very high z-index, thus being on top of everything.
- I have a different design that I must apply to the calendar, made by some artists. It's pretty good, but I'm not sure I will be able to make it with the calendars HTML as it is.

Also, the replacement must happen everywhere - both in gridviews and in standalone controls.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I could also go for a variant where I use some custom gridview column types and calendar types that are made by me.

Currently I'm a bit overwhelmed by the complexity of DevExpress.

Answer (score 0):

In repsonse to the second part of your question, the design of the calendar control - you can actually edit the DevExpress editors CSS file (called **styles.css**) that will be included in what ever DevExpress theme you use (i.e. **App_Themes\Aqua\Editors**).

If you open up the CSS file, all the styles related to the calendar are prefixed with **.dxeCalendar**, editing these should reflect on all calendar controls (be it in a ASPxGridView or stand alone editor etc).

I am not sure about the positioning of the drop down calendar off the top of my head but you should check out the DevExpress support center - there really helpful!

www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is - CSS alone will not do. I'd have to modify the HTML output as well. :( Plus, I need to add some features to the calendar too (like month-only view, where you can pick a month, but not a specific date).

Comment: If you want to hide the dates then you could try overriding this CSS tag...

    <style type="text/css">
        .dxMonthGrid
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

Then set these properties...

            HighlightToday="False" 
            HighlightWeekends="False" 
            ShowDayHeaders="False" 
            ShowTodayButton="False" 
            ShowWeekNumbers="False" 
            EnableYearNavigation="False" 
            ShowClearButton="False"

If you need to do major alterations DevExpress provide you with the source with your subscription :)

Comment: p.s. Appologies for the formatting i dont think you can space stuff out in a comment...